# Удаление элемента в ListView

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Есть данный адаптер

```
public class ListViewClearAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    ArrayList<itemSelect> objects;
    ListViewClearAdapter adapter = this;

    public ListViewClearAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<itemSelect> itemSelects)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = itemSelects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View customView = convertView;

        final itemSelect itemSelects = getItemList(position);

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            customView = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item_clear, null);

            customView.findViewById(R.id.ripple).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    objects.remove(position);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            customView.findViewById(R.id.ripple2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override public void onClick(View v)
                {

                }
            });

            TextView textView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText(itemSelects.name);
        }

        return customView;
    }

    itemSelect getItemList(int position)
    {
        return ((itemSelect) getItem(position));
    }
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку выполняю удаление из динамического массива `objects` и обновляю адаптер

```
customView.findViewById(R.id.ripple).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override public void onClick(View v)
            {
                objects.remove(position);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Но вместо того чтоб удалить нужный элемент он удаляет элементы последовательно снизу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не переназначаете обработчики при переиспользовании.

```
    customView = covertView;
    if (customView == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        customView = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item_clear, null);
    }
    customView.findViewById(R.id.ripple).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v)
        {
           objects.remove(position);
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

ЗЫ Используйте паттерн ViewHolder (см. например [здесь](http://androiddocs.ru/pattern-viewholder-v-realizacii-spiska-listview/)).

**UPD** ListView оптимизирован тким образом, чтобы переиспользовать view для других элементов. Т.е. создается столько view, сколько влезает на экран плюс-минус один-два. При прокрутке списка, новые view не создаются, а используются ранее созданные (тот самый convertView). При этом ваша задача по новому position перезаполнить данные, перенавесить обработчики (зависящие от position в частности).

У вас реализовано таким образом, что данные и обработчики заполняются только при первом добавлении view. Прокрутите вниз, увидите что установленный текст (`textView.setText(itemSelects.name);`) будет повторяться, притом как попало.
Это неверно.  Таким образом, вам надо заполнять данные и вешать обработчики не только при convertView==null.

По паттерну ViewHolder... Он позволяет избежать лишних дорогостоящих findViewById. Подробнее см по ссылке выше.

Comment: Не понял, можно поподробнее

Comment: @Fasd обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, спас ситуацию )